# Why is my output txt file empty , I receive no errors when opening the text file

Tags: c++, ofstream

I am trying to figure out why my ofstream will not print anything in the txt file . The txt file is created successfully , and I receive no errors when opening said file . But when I open it , it is empty. The ifstream file is also opened successfully and read with no errors. I included some bits of code below:

*Opening and checking*

```
 outfile.open(outName.c_str());
if(outfile.fail())
{
    cout << "Cannot open output file .Aborting "<<endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

*Processing of ifstream file and outputting to ofstream file*

```
 char ch;
int count=0;
infile.get(ch);
while(!infile.eof())
{
    ch=tolower(ch);
    if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
    {
        count++;
        if(count<=8)
            outfile << ch;

    }
    else
    {
        if(ch == ';')
        {
            outfile << ch;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    infile.get(ch);
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Did you check that infile was opened correctly? Try to output to stdout first.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should close the file to flush the buffer chars into the file.

Comment: `std::fstream` utilizes RAII. The file is closed while the object is destroyed.